# Numerical quadrature for Pareto distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, numerical-integration, numerics

I would like to numerically evaluate an integral of the following type, when evaluating $f(x)$ at any given point is numerically costly:
$$
\int_{x_m}^\infty x^{-\alpha}f(x) \, dx, \quad \alpha >1, x_m >0.
$$

My question is, what is the best way to do this. Or alternatively, is there some standard approach for such a problem. We may assume that $f(x)$ is globally bounded.

The two possible options I have in mind are using (i) Gauss-Legendre quadrature with a change of variables to change the limits of integration from $[x_m, \infty]$ to $[-1,1]$ or (ii) Gauss–Laguerre quadrature to integrate $g(x) = x^{-\alpha}e^x f(x)$.

However, I don't know anything about the stability (and other) properties of these quadrature schemes after the change of variables. For instance, using Gauss-Laguerre quadrature, $g(x)$ as defined above would not be globally bounded and I suspect might not produce a good approximation for the integral.

I am thus wondering, if there is some standard quadrature scheme for these sort of integrals with a polynomially decaying weight.

Comment: There is no general answer without placing strong restrictions on $f.$ The reason is that upon writing $g(x) = x^{-\alpha}f(x),$ it becomes clear that you are asking how to evaluate *any* indefinite integral whatsoever.  Please supply more details.

Comment: Fair enough, but still that's often the way these integrals are written for the different quadrature schemes. In my case, we may assume that $\alpha >2$ and $f(x) \sim x$ for large $x$; or put another way, $\alpha >1$ and $f(x)$ is globally bounded.